# firebase app check is not working with web client?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, recaptcha, firebase-app-check

I have followed the official firebase app check installation tutorial:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web/recaptcha-enterprise-provider

And I'm only getting errors.

1. I created and setup firebase project
2. Added app check library to my app
3. copy pasted app check initialization for web:

```
const appCheck = initializeAppCheck(firebaseApp, {
  provider: new ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider(
    "my_recaptcha_key_here"
  ),
  isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true, // Set to true to allow auto-refresh.
});
```

4. Enforced storage, enforced firestore from my console.

According to the tutorial, thats all you need to do.

RESULT:

Can't access anything from firestore, I get:

```
 @firebase/app-check: FirebaseError: AppCheck: ReCAPTCHA error. (appCheck/recaptcha-error).
```

When uploading to storage, I get:

```
@firebase/app-check: FirebaseError: AppCheck: Fetch server returned an HTTP error status. HTTP status: 403. (appCheck/fetch-status-error).
```

Why is this happening, I have done all the steps in the tutorial?

Comment: can you refer to the link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70878289/15774176 is it helpful?

Comment: Do you got solutions?

Comment: Do you have a typo at ```true,```, with an extra comma(```,```)

Answer (score 9):

Please make sure that the App URL is added to the reCAPTCHA allowed domains list.